Action principle dependent on spacetime-topology?
Consider the Lagrangian density
$$L(\phi, \nabla \phi, g) = g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_{\mu} \phi \nabla_{\nu} \phi$$
If one varies the action as usual, then one finds the equation
$$\delta S = \int_{\mathcal{M}} dV \Big( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi} - \nabla_k\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\nabla_k \phi)} \Big) \delta \phi + \oint_{\partial \mathcal{M}} dS \frac{\partial L}{\partial \nabla \phi} \delta \phi$$
The surface term is usually assumed to vanish -- one then gets the Euler-Lagrange equations of motion. This approach/condition relies on the spacetime having a boundary, such that Gauß divergence theorem can be applied (making a divergence-like term into a surface integral). However, if one assumes e.g. a compact spacetime without boundary, how does one obtain the Euler-Lagrange equations, since then one does not arrive at the second integral and much less does it vanish, right?
One way to resolve this would be that there are topological requirements for a Lorentzian manifold to be a spacetime, e.g. a spacetime may not be a closed manifold or something similar. Are there any sensible topological requirements on the manifold for it to be spacetime?

The divergence theorem does not require a manifold with a boundary. If the manifold is compact without boundary  the second term just vanishes automatically as the integration space is the empty set.

Hm, this would of course be a nice explanation. However, the sources I looked up all require the manifold to have a boundary (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#For_compact_Riemannian_manifolds_with_boundary). Do you know a good source where the boundary-less-ness of the theorem is featured?

I don't have a source for this as it is well-known. However maybe two ways to see this are the following: If you cut a small cap out of a surface without boundary this will generate a boundary term. Not take the cap to be of infinitesimal size. Then the integral is approximated well by the size of the manifold * the value of the integrated. The integrated is some (finite) constant due to boundedness of regular function on compact manifolds. Thus the integral has to vanish in the limit where the cap is infinitesimal. Secondly if you look at the wikipedia proof sketch you see that

the proof is identical on manifolds without boundary (where you only need the first case they consider).

I see. Thank you for your comments. If you write them as an answer I could accept them.

Actually, the very proof of Stokes’ theorem (after simplifying things via a partition of unity) is by considering two cases: one where the manifold has a boundary and one where the manifold has no boundary. In the boundary-less case the integral $\int_M d\zeta$ is shown by explicit calculation to be $0$. So Stokes’ theorem $\int_Md\zeta=\int_{\partial M}\zeta$ holds even in the boundary-less case because the LHS vanishes by explicit computation while the RHS vanishes by definition. You can look up any proof in any differential geometry textbook and you’ll immediately see the case distinction.

Having said that, there are topological restrictions on a manifold in order for it to carry a Lorentzian metric: a smooth manifold carries a Lorentzian metric if and only if it is non compact, or it is compact with vanishing Euler characteristic (so that it admits a nowhere-vanishing vector field).

@peek-a-boo Thank you for your answer. A last follow-up, if you dont mind: in relevant literature, this topic seems to be a bit passed over. Take eg Minkowski spacetime, which has no boundary. Still the requirement standardly assumed in order to obtain the equations of motion from the action principle is for fields to decay fast enough so that the surface integral vanishes. But since Minkowski has no boundary, the surface integral vanishes anyhow. Could it be that on open manifolds the "boundary" is implicitly meant to be the limit or the conformal boundary? Am I missing sth fundamental here?

Yes, Minkowski space is just $\Bbb{R}^4$ as a smooth manifold, so it has no boundary. When considering the divergence/Stokes theorem for compactly supported objects, there will be no boundary term as I said above. However, even when you deal with things vanish rapidly enough (even if not compactly supported), you can prove a divergence/Stokes theorem. For instance in $\Bbb{R}^n$, let $F$ be a smooth vector field such that $\text{div}(F)\in L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$ and such that $|x|^{n-1}|F(x)|\to 0$ as $|x|\to\infty$. Then, we can also prove that $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\text{div}(F),dV=0$.

The proof for this is that $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\text{div}(F),dV=\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}\int_{B_R(0)}\text{div}(F),dV$, where $B_R(0)$ is the closed ball of radius $R$, by the dominated convergence theorem (since $\text{div}(F)\in L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$). Now, for each $R$, we can use the usual divergence theorem to transform this into a surface integral $\int_{\partial B_R(0)}\langle F,\nu\rangle,d\sigma$. This now vanishes as $R\to\infty$ due to our decay assumption on $F$. So, this is what people mean when they say “decay fast enough at infinity so the surface integrals vanish”.

@peek-a-boo Splendid! This helped me a great deal. Thank you so very much. If you want to convert this to an answer (copy & paste), I will gladly accept it as is.

you should write up your own answer :) because what we just talked about seems very different from the original question.
